# Low pass filter symmetry

Tags: filter, high-voltage, low-pass

I wanted to know which one of these circuits would be better to protect the transformer.
The low pass filters are used as protection to block the high high frequency from the resonant circuit as the high voltage transformer is quite susceptible to the overvoltage that the resonant circuit may produce.
(This is my first post here so any feedback is more than welcome)

[image: Protection filters]

Comment: Are you trying to protect the transformer or the high frequency circuit

Comment: The transformer.

Comment: I don't think you'll have to worry about the transformer since, if it's a mains one (as shown), its inductance will be in the range of Henry, which will attenuate considerably any high frequencies coming to it. But if you think you need a filter, then I'd use an LC rather than an RC, and I'd use C on the converter side, since that is the direction of the current flow. Even if it's AC current, the meter on the wall will register a positive value. Unless you have a generator (drawing the trafo on the left suggests to me that's where the power comes from, left to right)?

Comment: The threats don't stack up with the cited potential victims.

Comment: The purpose of these networks (generally L-C or coupled chokes - C) is to prevent the "propagation" or "emission" of "radio frequencies" likely to interfere with other equipments ...